# Javascript can't access global variables outside function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using google map geocoding to  get latitude,longitude value from address.Here is my code,

```
var latd;
var lond;
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       console.log(place);
       var latd = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
       var lond = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
     }
    console.log(latd);
});
//console.log(latd);
```

When access the variable `latd` outside function, its value seems `undefined`. What's the issue with the above code?

Update1:

```
    getlatlang(address);
    console.log(latd);//Not defined


function getlatlang(address)
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            //console.log(place);
            latd = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lond = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
             return latd,lond;
             }

     });
}
```

Comment: remove keyword 'var' from if condition.

Answer (score 1):

First, because the variable you try to access into your condition will be accessible only into the context if. The variable your redeclared into if is new variable.

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   console.log(place);
   var latd = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
   var lond = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
   console.log(latd, lond)
}
```

You can change with this:

```
var latd;
var lond;
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(place);
      latd = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      lond = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
   }
   console.log(latd);
});
```

**Update**

`geocoder.geocode` is an async function. You have to wait until it's done. 
Your variable after the `geocoder.geocod` is executed even if the geocoder hasn't yet finished to be executed. So your variable is always undefined, because you create a variable with undefined value.

**Note:** All your action should be into the callback function, of geocoder, otherwise, it will always undefined.

Comment: With the above how can I access as `geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    console.log(place);
                latd = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                lond = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

           
  
   }
    
   });
  console.log(latd);` like this

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks.I got it!

Comment: All async functions work this way!

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have access to lat, long outside the function simply assign them and do not create them inside. You can read more about [JavaScript Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

```
    var latd;
    var lond;
     geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(place);
            latd = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lond = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
         }
      console.log(latd);
     });
     //console.log(latd);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I 've did it.But still it remains undefined when access from out of the function

Comment: Do you have a living example? Check whether condition `status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK` is `true`